# Running out of RAM on large AQL query | Trying to split a collection into two

Tags: arangodb

In my efforts to solve my issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47445387/635160), I'm using ArangoDb's AQL language to split a collection into two. As creating graphs can only be done on "normalized" collections. But my query is eating up all of my RAM (16gb).

```
FOR comment IN collection_name
    COLLECT author = comment.author
    , subreddit = comment.subreddit
    WITH COUNT INTO counter
    RETURN {author, counter, subreddit}
```

Is there a way I could dump the results directly to disk without pulling it into RAM? Or a way I could split it directly without using a query?

Comment: It could be a bug related to this: https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/3806

Comment: How much data do you have before running the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem here is, that the `COLLECT` statement works in memory. Since your collection has 40 million documents and you want to work with all of them, and they give 72.424.492 uniq items to collect this won't work out.

To create the subset collection you desire you create,

one can use the [`OPTIONS { ignoreErrors: true }`](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.2/AQL/Operations/Insert.html#setting-query-options) to create this subset.

Since your `author`-field may contain strings that are not allowed in the `_key` field (which we need to identify and skip duplicates with the `ignoreErrors`-option) you can use [`MD5()`](https://docs.arangodb.com/latest/AQL/Functions/String.html#md5) to create a `_key` uniq to each author. A resulting query creating one author entry per uniq author could look like that:

```
db._query(`
  FOR item IN RawSubReddits
    INSERT {
      _key: MD5(item.author),
      author: item.author
      } INTO authors
        OPTIONS { ignoreErrors: true }`);
```

once you have these, you could update a count from an edge collection:

```
 db._query(`
   FOR onesubred IN RawSubReddits
     INSERT {
       _from: CONCAT('authors/', MD5(onesubred.author)),
       _to: CONCAT('RawSubReddits/', onesubred._key)
     } INTO  authorsToSubreddits")
```

[This post](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/3808#issuecomment-349596743) on github can provide more information.